# Images for iPhone 4 and 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, cocoa-touch

I was wondering, because I use this method to get my application to pick background image automatically based on if it is an iPhone 4 or 5 screen:

```
NSString *background = @"image.png";
NSString *background5 = @"image-568.png"; 

CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    // code for 4-inch screen
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:background5]];
} else {
    // code for 3.5-inch screen
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:background]];

}
```

But my question is. If i have a image for a button that i also want to be automatically picked, can I use the same code for the button that I used for the background:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:background]];
```

Or should I have some other code for the button? Im using Xcode 4.5

Answer (score 1):

You should use the UIButton's methods to set images:

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[button setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or

```
[button setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: [button setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; (I get an error that says: Use of undeclared identifier "button"

Comment: The "button" is an example that refers to the UIButton object you should previosluy created in your code.